# Displaying result of mysql query

Tags: php, sql, median

I have managed to use other questions on here in order to find the median result in my table, but now I am unsure of how to print this result.

This is my PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT x.price 
          FROM price_pints x, price_pints y 
          GROUP BY x.price 
          HAVING SUM(    
                       SIGN( 
                             1 - SIGN( y.price - x.price ) 
                           ) 
                    ) / COUNT( * ) > .5 
          LIMIT 1"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "The average price of a pint ". $row['type']. " is £".$row['x.price(price)'];
echo "<br />";
}
```

The result shows up as 5 when I test the  sql query in phpmyadmin, but it doesn't display when I echo the result.

Previously I calculated the avg and that was easy to print as:

```
echo "The average price of a pint ". $row['type']. " is £".$row['AVG(price)'];
```

Now I am stuck as how to change the .$row[price(price)]                          ^^^

Comment: Stop using mysql, instead use PDO just search for it

Comment: Do you want the median of *all* prices, or the median *per type*, in a Group fashion?

Comment: For all the prices. I have calculated the correct answer but I just can't display it.

Somewhere in `£".$row['x.price(price)'];` I am missing the point..

Comment: What does your type column contain out of interest? As you will only be returning one value here of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest, consider moving to PDO or mySQLi, as all `mysql_` commands are being deprecated.

Your PHP needs to read;

```
echo "The average price of a pint ". $row['type']. " is £".$row['price'];
```

However, I'm wondering what you expect to be returned in your Type column? As you're not selecting it above, and further you will only be returning one single value, and one type of course, even though you're calculating a Median over all prices.

At the very least, your SQL would be;

```
      SELECT x.price, x.type 
      FROM price_pints x, price_pints y 
      GROUP BY x.price 
      HAVING SUM(    
                   SIGN( 
                         1 - SIGN( y.price - x.price ) 
                       ) 
                ) / COUNT( * ) > .5 
      LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I see my type is now totally unnecessary. I'm sorry for making things seem more complicated than they actually are. It's working now. Cheers!

Comment: Haha... No problems at all! You didn't make it confusing at all, just curious! Glad that you got it working... Please do feel free to accept the answer if it's helped! Congrats!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to look into using mysqli or PDO to run your query, you're completely susceptible to sql injections using mysql_query and its depreciated anyhow, and will soon be removed. That being said if your query is working when run directly on your databse it should run from php.

Check to see how many rows you are returning

```
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result)
```

Make sure you are referencing the proper columns.

Comment: Noted, I will look into PDO now.

The issue is within this line:

`echo "The average price of a pint ". $row['type']. " is £".$row['x.price(price)'];`

I don't know how to get this to display "5" like the query does.